# Alternative color of the box creating with POLYGON

Tags: opengl

I am to alternative box color for each polygon.

```
void display(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int evenoddcheck = 0;
    int height = 50;
    int width = 100;

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for( int a=0 ; a <= 1000 ; a=a+100 ) 
    {
        for( int b=0 ; b <= 500 ; b=b+50 ) 
        {
            if( evenoddcheck % 2 == 0 )
            {
                glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);          
            }
            else {
                glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);          
            }

            glVertex2i(b,a);
            glVertex2i(b,width+a);
            glVertex2i(height+b,width+a);
            glVertex2i(height+b,a);
            evenoddcheck++;
        }
    }

    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}
```

work fine with single color, but when i render code it shows
http://s11.postimage.org/3ms3mmc4j/box.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code first I also found same problem as you. I kept the glBegin() and glEnd inside the second for loop like this then it works fine because in each loop you draw ploygon and start the next so here you can use GL_POLYGON. But in you code as describe by @dantenwolf you can't get correct result by using GL_POLYGON you have to use GL_QUADS.

```
for( int a=0 ; a <= 100 ; a=a+10 )
{        for( int b=0 ; b <= 50 ; b=b+5 ).
    {

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        if( evenoddcheck % 2 == 0 )
        {
            glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        }
        else {
            glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        }

        glVertex2i(b,a);
        glVertex2i(b,width+a);
        glVertex2i(height+b,width+a);
        glVertex2i(height+b,a);
        glEnd();

        evenoddcheck++;
    }
}
glFlush();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using GL_POLYGON, which only works for convex, coplanar primitives. What you're drawing is a bunch of vertices on a regular grid, connecting edges by quads: This clearly doesn't meet those constraints; also it completely messes up your topology. Simple fix: Replace GL_POLYGON with GL_QUADS.

Oh and you shouldn't use immediate mode (you know glBegin … glEnd) in the first place. It's been out of fashion for well over 15 years now (getting close to 20).